# Double unique counts in python

Tags: python, pandas, whitespace

I have golf data from the PGA Tour that I am trying to clean. Originally, I had white space in front of some of the hole scores. This is what a unique count looked like:

```
df["Hole Score"].value_counts()

Out[76]: 
4     566072
5     272074
3     218873
6      48596
 4     38306
 5     19728
2      17339
 3     15093
7       7750
        4232
 6      3011
8       1313
 2      1080
 7       389
9        369
10        66
 8        61
11        38
1         27
 9        20
Name: Hole Score, dtype: int64
```

I was able to run a whitespace remover function that got rid of leading white space. However, my count values function returns the same frequency counts:

```
df["Hole Score_2"].value_counts()
Out[74]: 
4     566072
5     272074
3     218873
6      48596
4      38306
5      19728
2      17339
3      15093
7       7750
        4232
6       3011
8       1313
2       1080
7        389
9        369
10        66
8         61
11        38
1         27
9         20
Name: Hole Score_2, dtype: int64
```

For reference, this is the helper function that I used:

```
def remove_whitespace(x):
    try:
        x = "".join(x.split())

    except:
        pass
    return x

df["Hole Score_2"] = df["Hole Score"].apply(remove_whitespace)
```

My question: How do I get the unique counts to list one Hole Score per count? What could be causing the double counting?

Comment: Looks like Hole Score has a dtype of int. What do you mean stripping a whitespace on an int?

Comment: @sharatpc I don't think so. They're performing string operations on it.

Comment: Have you considered trying to use ‘strip()’ instead of ‘split()’ and then convert x to an int value with ‘int(x)’?

Comment: then just use df['Hole Score'].str.strip. is the helper function needed?